# Azure Pipeline Deploy DacPac to Azure SQL - How to add firewall rule?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, dacpac

I've got an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline and I'm trying to deploy a SQL Database.

Here is the YAML for the task:

```
steps:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Dev/Test Connection'
    AuthenticationType: aadAuthenticationIntegrated
    ServerName: 'myserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'mydb'
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PATHTOMYFILE.Db.dacpac'
    DeleteFirewallRule: false
```

The error in the log are somewhat vague:

> [debug]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at...

However the log also says this:

> [debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]*** An unexpected failure occurred: One or more errors occurred..
> [debug]No Firewall Rule was added

I know that a firewall rule must be added for IPs trying to Access Azure SQL. My understanding is that the task will try to create the firewall exception for me based on the IP address of the Agent being used. But the log says "no firewall rule was added". You may notice that I have set `DeleteFirewallRule: false`. I wasn't sure if the rules were getting created and then deleted, this setting would keep them available for me to check. But again, none were created.

I can't add the firewall rule manually in the Azure Portal because the Agent will be different each time the release pipeline runs. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: I've been looking at the source .PS1 script for this task. It seems that the message "No Firewall Rule was added" is not an indication of a failure. This happens at the end of the process. It is saying that no rules need to be deleted because none were added.

Comment: OK. Not sure yet but I think the problem is not the firewall at all, I think it is due to the auth method selected in the task (aadAuthenticationIntegrated). I'll keep testing and update the question/answer when I figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages for this task are not very clear at all. After trying a bunch of different ways to resolve this, I took a shot at changing the authentication mode.

```
steps:
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: 'Azure SQL DacpacTask'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Dev/Test Connection'
    ServerName: 'myserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'mydb'
    SqlUsername: '$(dbdeployuser)'
    SqlPassword: '$(dbdeploypassword)'
    DacpacFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/PATHTOMYFILE.Db.dacpac'
    DeleteFirewallRule: false
```

Once I did this, it worked. So the problem is not the firewall at all.

Comment: Glad to know the problem has been solved. You can accept it as the answer and it could help people who met the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, thanks of the reminder. I thought that if I answered my own question it would "accept it" automatically.

Comment: Thanks for returning with a solution. I'm yet to confirm that `aadAuthenticationIntegrated` through a service connection works.